# Grails data binding to command object with maps - convert key to number

Tags: grails, data-binding, groovy

I have a Grails command object with a list of maps.  The map key is intended to be a numeric domain object ID.

```
class MyCommand {
  def grid = [].withDefault { [:] }
}
```

Data binding to the list/map is working in general because of the dynamic list expansion.

However, in the POST, the map keys are being bound as Strings and I want them to be Longs, as they are when the form is initially populated.  I want `foo[123]` in my map, not `foo['123']`.

Alternatively I would be satisfied if the `[]` operators found the correct value given a numeric ID key to look up.  In other words, if I could get `foo[123]` to return the same value as `foo['123']`, that would work too.

Any way to get this to work the way I want to?  Maybe strongly type the map?

Or a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can `inject` the property into the map to convert a `String` key to `Long`. For example:

```
def myMap = [:] << ['1': "name"] << ['Test': "bobo"]
def result = myMap.inject([:]){map, v ->
   def newKey = v.key.isNumber() ? v.key.toLong() : v.key
   map[newKey] = v.value
   map
}

assert myMap['1'] == 'name'
assert result[1L] == 'name'
assert result['Test'] == 'bobo'
```